# How to show a simple list of events in a content query webpart in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

This should be really simple in SharePoint, but I can't figure out how to do it:
I simply want to show a list of upcoming events from a calendar in a content query webpart:

12. Aug 12:00 Meeting re new sales plan
13. Aug 09:00 Party

I can use the content query webpart (CQWP) to do this for pages or documents or news articles, but apparently not calendar items.
I can create something like this with the list view webpart, but then I can't control the exact layout and styles. That is why I want to use the content query webpart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the problem you are having exactly? The CQWP supports calendar lists. Perhaps [this screencast](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/VideoOnDemand/Calendars-ConsolidationWithContentQueryWP/Calendars-ConsolidationWithContentQueryWP.html) can help you.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly what I needed. I did not have "Calendar" as an option when creating the query, and it turned out it was because collaboration features was not enabled. When I enabled them I was able to do what I wanted in the CQWP.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the DataFormWebPart, using SharePoint designer the look and feel is easily controlled (it's Xsl that transforms to Html, so you can do anything you want to get it to show in your own branding / design)